# When asking a question, tips aren't closable on small screens

Tags: bug, user-interface

When asking a question on a small screen (the <html> is less than 814px wide), the tips, like "Summarize the problem" don't open/close when clicked.

I mean these tips (under the cursor):
[image]

Here's the video on a small screen: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J8gRKJyWlWuy59Kb9iJfTXY_gT3O0xCW/view?usp=sharing
And on a wider one: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aO57298U-PxiCjqz7ytBl25tsxinLyGd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sidenote: This bug may be more useful if it could include a screenshot indicating the problem

Comment: What do you mean by the tips not being closable (or openable as per the body)? They don't seem to be closable/openable on larger windows, either. As far as I can tell, they are completely omitted on small windows and always presents on larger windows.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've uploaded a video for better understanding.

Comment: @Kastet6398 it would be better if you upload an image directly here on Stack Overflow rather than giving us a link to Google Drive.

Answer (score 9):

Can repro on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, on Windows / Chrome `122.0.6261.129 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.
Make sure you don't have the "Ask Wizard" enabled:

[image]

The moment you expand the *"Step 1: Draft your question"* collapsible, the following errors show in the console:

[image]

I suspect this prevents the click / touch handlers from being registered in the inner dropdowns.

Interestingly, the second error also appears on wider screens, when you toggle one of the inner dropdowns. (On larger screens, they *do* still work)